# Which Linux commands are included with or part of the shell?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to figure out the different components of Linux and how they work together, and I have a terminology related question. The terminal runs the shell, which is usually Bash. Does that mean that Linux commands (e.g. ls, mkdir, copy) are part of Bash (or the shell in general)?

Comment: Run `type ls` and the shell will tell you it came from `/usr/bin/ls` instead of being part of bash itself.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [the Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Or [Super User](https://superuser.com). It's not specific to writing code so it's off topic here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ok. But there is a helpful answer already. Do I copy it and delete the question? or keep the question?

Comment: @mradwan, a moderator can move the question and the answer together, but that's only appropriate if the question doesn't already exist in answered form on the destination site, which would surprise me very much.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy One more thing please. Stackoverflow suggests that I edit the question and make it useful. I don't see a way to improve it, without changing it completely (e.g. asking about something in particular in Bash scripting). Is that ok? But I am afraid then that the answer below, and those comments would make no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, commands such as `ls`, `mkdir`, `cp` (POSIX does not define a command named
`copy`) are not implemented by Bash. They are external commands as you
can learn with `type`:

```
$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
ls is /usr/bin/ls
ls is /bin/ls
$ type -a mkdir
mkdir is /usr/bin/mkdir
mkdir is /bin/mkdir
$ type -a cp
cp is /usr/bin/cp
cp is /bin/cp
```

On desktops GNU based Linux distros such as Debian or Slackware they
are implemented by [GNU coreutils
package](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils). On embedded systems
Busybox or Toybox are commonly used instead of GNU coreutils for its
smaller size and memory footprint (and Bash is usually not used on
such systems).

That being said, there are some commands which are implemented within
Bash for example `pwd` or `cd`:

```
$ type pwd
pwd is a shell builtin
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```